# Why doesn't a Dataset accept its own schema for type casts?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm struggling to understand how to craft Dataset schemas. I have a dataset from an aggregation with the key tuple in one column, and the aggregate in the second:

```
> ds.show
+------+------+
|    _1|    _2|
+------+------+
|[96,0]| 93439|
|[69,0]|174386|
|[42,0]| 12427|
|[15,0]|  2090|
|[80,0]|  2626|
|[91,0]| 71963|
|[64,0]|   191|
|[37,0]|    13|
|[48,0]| 13898|
|[21,0]|  2510|
|[59,0]|  1874|
|[32,0]|   373|
| [5,0]|  1075|
|[97,0]|     2|
|[16,0]|   492|
|[11,0]| 34040|
|[76,0]|     4|
|[22,0]|  1216|
|[60,0]|   522|
|[33,0]|   287|
+------+------+
only showing top 20 rows

> ds.schema
StructType(StructField(_1,StructType(StructField(src,IntegerType,false), StructField(dst,IntegerType,false)),true), StructField(_2,LongType,false))
```

Why can't I apply this schema?

```
> val mySchema = StructType(StructField("_1",StructType(StructField("src",IntegerType,false), 
                                                        StructField("dst",IntegerType,false)),true), 
                            StructField("_2",LongType,false))
> ds.as[mySchema]

Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:41: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fields: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: java.util.List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (fields: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField, org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField)
       val returnSchema = StructType(StructField("_1",StructType(StructField("src",IntegerType,false),      
                                                      ^
```

I've also unsuccessfully tried to reflect a Scala `case class`:

```
> final case class AggSchema(edge: (Int, Int), count: Long)
> ds.as[AggSchema]

Name: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedException
Message: Invalid call to dataType on unresolved object, tree: 'edge
StackTrace: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute.dataType(unresolved.scala:59)
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach doesn't because schema is not a type. Schema is just an object which describes Catalyst types of the column. In other words schema is just a metadata required to interpret values stored in `DataFrame`. Without it `DataFrame` is nothing more than `Dataset[Row]` and `o.a.s.sql.Row` is pretty much a `Seq[Any]`.

The second  approach doesn't work because names of the fields don't match the schema. Since names of the columns.

```
case class Edge(src: Int, dst: Int)

val df = Seq((Edge(96, 0), 93439L)).toDF
```

Either don't use names at all:

```
df.as[((Int, Int), Long)]
```

or use schema that matches used case class, for example

```
case class AggSchema(edge: Edge, count: Long)

df.toDF("edge", "count").as[AggSchema]
```